# if $R = \{(x,y) \in \Bbb{R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ and $S = R^2$. I need write $R \circ S$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, relations

I haven’t had any mathematics since high school (have been a while) and now i’m trying with the basics in logic and set theory but of course i don’t get it easy.

I have this operation: if $R = \{(x,y)\in {\Bbb R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ and $S = \Bbb R^2$. I need write $R \circ S$, but I’m having troubles. I know it isn’t $R$.
Using the definition:
$$
R \circ S = \{(x,z) \in {\Bbb R}^2 : \exists y\ [y \in {\Bbb R} \text{ and } (x,y) \in S \text{ and } (y,z) \in R]\} 
$$
Now I replace
$$
 R \circ S = \{(x,z)\in {\Bbb R}^2 : \exists y\ [y \in {\Bbb R} \text{ and } (x,y) \in R^2 \text{ and }x^2 + y^2 = 1\} 
$$
I thought it ends $R \circ S = R$, but it doesn’t, and I don’t know how to continue from here.

Comment: How do you define $R\circ S$ for two sets $R$ and $S$?

Comment: @DietrichBurde presumably $R \circ S$ is meant to denote the composition of two relations.

Comment: @Jose It is unclear when you are referring to $R$ and when you are referring to $\Bbb R$. Please clarify this by formatting your math in the way that I have demonstrated in my recent edit to your question.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Any subset of $A \times B$ can be interpreted as a relation between $A$ and $B$. So in this context, $R$ is effectively the multivalued function $f(x) = \pm \sqrt{1 - x^2}$ over domain $-1 \leq x \leq 1$.

Comment: Sorry. i’m don’t know how to type R ‘the set of real numbers’. S = R^2.    I’m using the seme notation in the book, R and S are relations

Comment: I'm not familiar with composition of non-functional relation ships.  So if $A=\{(1,2),(2,3),(1,4)\}$ and $B=\{(2,5),(3,5),(3,7)\}$ then $A\circ B=\{(1,5),(2,5),(2,7)\}$ ? But the for any $P \subset R\times R$ wouldn't $P\circ (R\times R) = P$ trivially?

Comment: No. Keep A = {(1,2), (2,3), (1,4)}. then A ° N X N isn’t A because (2,2) ∈ A° NxN but (2,2) ∉ A. but A ° Identidad N = A

Comment: Why is $(2,2)\in A\circ N\times N$?  There is no $(2,a),(a,2)$ that... oh... that was a foolish oversight... But is $P' = \{a\in R| \exists (a,x)\in P\}$ then isn't $P\circ R\times R = P'\times R$ .... which I guess isn't that trivial a results.  BUt wouldn't $P\circ (\mathbb R\times \mathbb R)=[-1,1]\times \mathbb R$?

Comment: So... to make sure I get this.  If $A$ and $B$ are releations on $M$ then $A\circ B = \{(a,b)|\exists x\in M; (a,x)\in A, (x,b) \in B\}$? ... If so this would mean $P\circ (\mathbb R\times R)= \{(a,b)|\exists y\in \mathbb R, (a,y)\in P; (y,b)\in \mathbb R\times\mathbb R\}=\{(a,z)|\exists y\in \mathbb R, (a,y)\in P;z\in \mathbb R\}=\{(a,z)|\exists y: a^2 + y^2=1\}=\{(a,z)|a^2 \le 1\}=[-1,1]\times \mathbb R$.  Correct?

Comment: i don’t know. i can’t follow the last two steps. you know z ∈ R. and ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $R = \{\langle x,y\rangle \in {\Bbb R}^2 : x^2 + y^2 = 1\}$ and $S = \Bbb R^2$

$$\begin{align}R\circ S & =\{\langle x,z\rangle:\exists y~.(\langle x,y\rangle\in S\wedge\langle y,z\rangle \in R)\}&&\text{def'n of }\circ\\[1ex]&=\{\langle x,z\rangle:\exists y~.(\langle x,y\rangle\in\Bbb R^2\wedge(\langle y,z\rangle\in\Bbb R^2\wedge y^2+z^2=1))\}&&\text{def'n }S, R\\[1ex]&\text{as you had (mostly); note that it was $\langle y,z\rangle\in R$ rather that $\langle x,y\rangle$.}\\[1ex]R\circ S&=\{\langle x,z\rangle:\exists y~.(x\in\Bbb R\wedge y\in\Bbb R\wedge z\in\Bbb R\wedge y^2+z^2=1)\}&&\text{def'n of }\Bbb R^2\\[1ex]&=\{\langle x, z\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:\exists y\in\Bbb R~. y^2=1-z^2\}&&\text{rearrange}\\[1ex]&=\{\langle x,z\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:z^2\leqslant 1\}&&\text{when does it exist?}\\[1ex]&=\{\langle x,z\rangle\in\Bbb R^2:-1\leq z\leq 1\}\\[1ex]&= \Bbb R\times[-1~..~1]\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. First observe that $(x,z) \in R^2$ if and only if there exists $y \in {\Bbb R}$ such that $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,z) \in R$, that is $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $y^2 + z^2 = 1$. I claim that $(x,z) \in R^2$ if and only if $x^2 = z^2 \leqslant 1$. Can you see why?

Next the composition of two relations is usually defined as follows (what you wrote is the definition of $S \circ R$, unless you have other conventions)
$$
(x,z) \in R \circ S \iff \text{there exists $y$ such that $(x,y) \in R$ and $(y,z) \in S$}.
$$
Thus, in your case
$$
(x,z) \in R \circ S \iff \text{there exists $y$ such that $x^2 + y^2 = 1$ and $ y^2 = z^2 \leqslant  1$} 
$$
Can you conclude from there?